# BD Neodatis - Problema duplicado de los objetos almacenados al cerrar la conexión

Tags: java, neodatis

Estoy probando la BD Neodatis en Java. 
La versión es 1.9.30.689

Almaceno objetos de la clase **Jugador**, que tiene 4 propiedades: nombre, edad, deporte y ciudad.
En la clase principal, **Ejemplo**, estoy abriendo la conexión, insertando los objetos y realizando algunas consultas. Si al finalizar cierro la conexión, al ejecutar nuevamente la clase, se insertan los objetos de nuevo por lo que se encontraran duplicados. Si no cierro la conexión, no se duplican, por lo que entiendo que simplemente se borran los datos anteriormente almacenados.

```
public class Jugador {

    /**
     * Propiedades 
     * 
     */
    private String nombre;
    private String deporte;
    private String ciudad;
    private int edad;


    /**
     * Constructores
     * 
     */
    public Jugador() {};

    public Jugador( 
        String nombre, 
        String deporte, 
        String ciudad, 
        int edad
    ) {
        super();
        this.nombre  = nombre;
        this.deporte = deporte;
        this.ciudad  = ciudad;
        this.edad    = edad;
    } 


    /**
     * Getters and setters
     * 
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre( String nombre ) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDeporte() {
        return deporte;
    }

    public void setDeporte( String deporte ) {
        this.deporte = deporte;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad( String ciudad ) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad( int edad ) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }


} // class


/**
 * Clase principal
 *
 */
public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open( 
            "d:\\test-neodatis.db" 
        ); 

        // Insertar objetos Jugador
        odb.store( new Jugador( 
            "Riu",    "baloncesto", "Salamanca", 14 ));
        odb.store( new Jugador( 
            "María",  "voleibol",   "Madrid",   14 )); 
        odb.store( new Jugador( 
            "Miguel", "tenis",      "Madrid",   15 )); 
        odb.store( new Jugador( 
            "Mario",  "baloncesto", "Cadiz",    15 )); 
        odb.store( new Jugador( 
            "Alicia", "tenis",      "Madrid",   14 ));


        /**
         * Queries
         * 
         */
        System.out.println( "Todos los jugadores..." );
        Objects<Jugador> res1 = odb.getObjects( 
            Jugador.class 
        );
        verResultados( res1 );

        System.out.println( "\n------------------------" );
        System.out.println( "Jugadores de tenis..." );
        IQuery query1 = new CriteriaQuery(
            Jugador.class,
            Where.equal( "deporte", "tenis" )
        );
        Objects<Jugador> res2 = odb.getObjects( query1 );
        verResultados( res2 );

        System.out.println( "\n------------------------" );
        System.out.println( "Jugadores de Madrid..." );
        ICriterion cr1 = Where.equal( "ciudad", "Madrid" );
        IQuery query2 = new CriteriaQuery(
            Jugador.class,
            cr1
        );
        Objects<Jugador> res3 = odb.getObjects( query2 );
        verResultados( res3 );

        System.out.println( "\n------------------------" );
        System.out.println( 
            "Jugadores de canicas, mayores de 15 años.." );
        ICriterion cr2 = new And()
            .add( Where.equal( "deporte", "canicas" ))
            .add( Where.gt( "edad", 15 ));
        IQuery query3 = new CriteriaQuery(
            Jugador.class,
            cr2
        );
        Objects<Jugador> res4 = odb.getObjects( query3 );
        verResultados( res4 );



        System.out.println( "\n------------------------" );
        System.out.println( "Cerrando conexión..." );
        odb.close();

    } //main

    /**
     * Shows the data
     *
     * @param      Objects<Jugador> x
     */
    private static void verResultados( Objects<Jugador> x ) {

        System.out.println( "Número objetos: " + x.size( ));

        int i = 1;
        while( x.hasNext( )) {

            Jugador j = x.next();

            System.out.println(
                ( i++ )      + ". " +
                j.getNombre()   + " * " +
                j.getDeporte()  + " * " +
                j.getCiudad()   + " * " +
                j.getEdad()
            );

        }
    }

} //class
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que he estado leyendo si no se definen como tal no existen claves únicas en las tablas que se van creando al hacer `.store()` de un objeto.

Entiendo que al no cerrar la conexion, como dices, simplemente se pierden los objetos y así al volver a ejecutar la clase no se encuentran duplicados.

Para definir un indice, por lo que yo se, se haría así en tu caso:

```
ClassRepresentation clase = odb.getClassRepresentation(Jugador.class);
String indexFields = { "nombre", "deporte" };
clase.addUniqueIndexOn("index1";, indexFields, true);
```

En este caso el índice sería `nombre` y `deporte`.